# How To Debug Legacy GWT Code With Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt, swt

I have a bit of a tricky problem. I have some really old (1.7) GWT code in a legacy application that I need to do some debugging on. Ideally, I would just update the code to a more modern version of GWT, but there are a bunch of custom widgets that make that difficult. As a result, I need to figure out some way to find tools that can work with the code as-is.

After a lot of digging and trial and error, I was able to get the 'hosted mode' to launch and run my application when run from the command line. When I try to do the same thing from within eclipse however, I am running into problems. The development shell launches, but when it tries to open the browser, it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] The browser widget class could not be instantiated
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147221164
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.error(Browser.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:236)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserWidget.<init>(BrowserWidget.java:242)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.moz.BrowserWidgetMoz.<init>(BrowserWidgetMoz.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.PlatformSpecific.createBrowserWidget(PlatformSpecific.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell.openNewBrowserWindow(GWTShell.java:504)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell.launchStartupUrls(GWTShell.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell.run(GWTShell.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell.main(GWTShell.java:321)
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here? Is there a better option for debugging my client side code?

**My Environment:**
Ubuntu 18.04 (x64)

Eclispe 4.6 neon (x86)

GWT 1.7

Java 7 (x86)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse is having trouble running it's internal browser (XPCOM / Mozilla).  Can you configure Eclipse to launch an external browser instead?

In the latest version of Eclipse, you can `Preferences -> General -> Web Browser`, there is the option "Use internal web browser". Select "Use external web browser" instead and check an external browser.

Comment: That was a good thought but no. As a matter of fact, Eclipse doesn't even let me select the internal browser. The option is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

GXT 1.x functions by running a java application which wraps a native browser widget - on linux, this is an old version of firefox - something like firefox 3.5 or earlier.

If memory serves, this functions by having a different distribution per platform - for example, on linux at http://www.gwtproject.org/versions.html there is a download for 1.7 (1.7.1 is latest, at least of 1.x builds). Note on that page there is a note for the linux downloads:

> The Linux distribution binaries are only for the x86 architecture. GWT hosted mode requires a 32-bit JVM and libraries. Other 32-bit architectures may be built from source, but are not supported, and will require a compatible build of Mozilla 1.7.12.

Are you sure you meet those requirements?